# why is quickfixj slowing down

Tags: quickfixj

i have an initiator app that sends orders to an acceptor app over fix protocol.

initiator app receives orders from a rabbit message queue and sends them over fix.

each new order triggers a replace , each replace triggers a cancel.

I am observing increasing delay ( 5+ minutes ) between time shown in quickfix log and and time execution report triggers onMessage method. eg. an execution report is logged at 16:10 in quickfix log and onMessage method is triggered at 16:15.

any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Probably QFJs internal queue is quite loaded with messages which take time to process. My guess is that there is probably much garbage collection going on which slows down the java process. Monitor the heap space and/or garbage collection to check for such problems.

Comment: Chris thank you very much. I appreciate the answer. I understand QFJ has a single queue that processes all messages going in and out. I will monitor memory usage and increase to accommodate too see if it can fix the problem.

Comment: That queue is only for incoming messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing gc frequency by adding -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m seems to work. may be a good idea to document sample production values for the vm for different loads.

Comment: Difficult because every setup is different. What are you doing in your fromApp method? Is there some lengthy processing that might slow down the whole process? How many messages are you processing per second?

Comment: incoming execution report is saved and several db updated are made , ~100 ms in total. obviously that's blocking the queue. we need to move db updates to another service. potentially hundreds of replace orders are sent in a loop , which also explains the delay.

Comment: You could offload the incoming messages to a separate queue which gets processed by a separate thread.