# quickfixj - delay between messages appearing in logs and actually processed with onMessage

Tags: metrics, quickfixj

I'm seeing a huge delay - over one minute when I'm doing a stress test of my quickfix app. I'm not doing anything fancy, I'm just calling rest endpoint with dto which is then translatedo to the fix message, and send with `session.sendToTarget`.

I've found this question - [why is quickfixj slowing down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73863883/why-is-quickfixj-slowing-down) but this isn't about GC, I can see that GC behavior isn't different than during normal load.

I was trying to add some metrics to see what is going on, I was trying to observe `socketInitiator.getQueueSize()` but it is always 0.

I'm thinking that during the stress test quickfix gives higher priority to sending rather than to receiving. Is it possible?, how I can check this? Do you have any other things that I can check?

Comment: I assume you are talking about incoming messages? How do you store your messages? What do you do in your application callback (show the code)?